# Any ways to make queue in observe

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I had a function which one has another call

```kotlin
    private fun request(){
        listener.onRequest(::setList)
    }
```

```kotlin
    private fun setList(list: List<Items>) {
        when(listType){ // listType is type of list which one should be used
            ViewUtils.SIMPLE -> setSimpleList(list)
            ViewUtils.TOUCHABLE -> setTouchableList(list)
            else -> createAdapter(list)
        }
    }
```

The onRequest overrides in other place. onRequest should get data from API and return it back

```kotlin
    override fun onRequest(
        setList: (List<Items>) -> Unit
    ) {
        if (mViewModel.listItemsResult.value.isNullOrEmpty()){
            mViewModel.loadListItems()
        }
        mViewModel.listItemsResult.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
            setList(it ?: listOf()))
        }
    }
```

The ViewModel gets data from API and posted it into listItemsResult
which one is `MutableLiveData<List<ListItems>>`

```kotlin
    fun loadListItems() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            try {
                val items = doRequestListSource()
                listItemsResult.postValue(items)
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                Log.e("getListItems", ex.message ?: "unknown error")
            }
        }
    }
```

doRequestListSource() gets data from API.

So. I have 1 or more than objects which one contains request() function. These objects are call onRequest to get data in the **same** time. After that data received from API (**data volume is different for each object**).

The problem: requests didn't get any queue, and if someone get response faster than other, then it will take that data.

Example:

expectation
**(same time)**

```
1 request -- 1 response (has medium volume of data)
2 request -- 2 response (has huge volume of data)
3 request -- 3 response (empty list)
```

reality
**(same time)**

```
1 request -- 3 response (empty list)
2 request -- 1 response (has medium volume of data)
3 request -- 2 response (has huge volume of data)
```

Is there any solutions to make a queue to get data from viewModel?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to synchronise the api calls not the observers.

you can do like this

```
var previuosJob: Job? = null
fun loadListItems() {
    previiuosJob?.join()

    prpeviousJob = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        try {
            val items = doRequestListSource()
            listItemsResult.postValue(items)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Log.e("getListItems", ex.message ?: "unknown error")
        }
    }
}
```